# Creating Sales Receipt with Sales Tax QBO API

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I am trying to create a sales receipt with tax included. I understand that the SalesTaxCodeId/SalesTaxCodeName has not been implemented for the Quickbooks API v2, so I'm trying to directly add a tax rate through the  field. Here is my request:

```
<SalesReceipt xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2" xmlns:ns2="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/qbopayroll/v1" xmlns:ns3="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/qbo">
<Header>
    <CustomerId idDomain="QBO">10</CustomerId>
    <TaxRate>5.00</TaxRate>
    <DepositToAccountId>52</DepositToAccountId>
</Header>
<Line>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Desc>asdfdsafds</Desc>
    <Amount>500.00</Amount>
    <Taxable>true</Taxable>
    <ItemId idDomain="QBO">5</ItemId>
    <Qty>1</Qty>
    <AccountId>52</AccountId>
</Line>
```

However, I'm getting a rather cryptic error as a response.

```
<Message>You must select a product/service or an account for each split line with either an amount or a billable $$customer$$.</Message><ErrorCode>BAD_REQUEST</ErrorCode><Cause>-13012</Cause>
```

This error only occurs if the tax rate results in a non-zero tax amount. i.e. if the tax rate is non-zero and the line item is taxable, otherwise the request goes through fine. The error code does not exist in any documentation I can find and the error message is not all that helpful. Does anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

EDIT: updated itembyid response

```
<Id idDomain="QBO">5</Id>
<SyncToken>2<SyncToken>
<MetaData>
    <CreateTime>2013-06-07T15:07:29-07:00</CreateTime>     
    <LastUpdatedTime>2013-08-02T14:34:47-07:00</LastUpdatedTime>
</MetaData>
<Name>Clothes</Name>
<Taxable>true</Taxable>
<UnitPrice>
    <Amount>123</Amount>
</UnitPrice>
<IncomeAccountRef>
    <AccountId idDomain="QBO">1</AccountId>
</IncomeAccountRef>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if the item with ID 5 exists in your account. You should also check the SalesTax settings.

[ QBO Account - 'Company' tab => Preferences ]

I tried with the same condition which you have mentioned above.
i.e. [ if the tax rate is non-zero and the line item is taxable ]
It worked fine. PFB details.

**Request XML**

```
<SalesReceipt xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2" xmlns:ns2="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/qbopayroll/v1" xmlns:ns3="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/qbo">
<Header>
    <CustomerId idDomain="QBO">3</CustomerId>
    <TaxRate>5.00</TaxRate>
    <DepositToAccountId>4</DepositToAccountId>
</Header>
<Line>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Desc>asdfdsafds</Desc>
    <Amount>500.00</Amount>
    <Taxable>true</Taxable>
    <ItemId idDomain="QBO">1</ItemId>
    <Qty>1</Qty>
</Line>
</SalesReceipt>
```

**Retrieve By ID**

```
<SalesReceipt xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2" xmlns:qbp="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/qbopayroll/v1" xmlns:qbo="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/qbo">
  <Id idDomain="QBO">75</Id>
  <SyncToken>0</SyncToken>
  <MetaData>
    <CreateTime>2013-08-02T22:10:41-07:00</CreateTime>
    <LastUpdatedTime>2013-08-02T22:10:41-07:00</LastUpdatedTime>
  </MetaData>
  <Header>
    <DocNumber>1038</DocNumber>
    <TxnDate>2013-08-02-07:00</TxnDate>
    <CustomerId idDomain="QBO">3</CustomerId>
    <SalesTaxCodeId idDomain="QBO">1</SalesTaxCodeId>
    <SalesTaxCodeName>IS_TAXABLE</SalesTaxCodeName>
    <SubTotalAmt>500.00</SubTotalAmt>
    <TaxRate>5</TaxRate>
    <TaxAmt>25.00</TaxAmt>
    <TotalAmt>525.00</TotalAmt>
    <ToBePrinted>false</ToBePrinted>
    <ToBeEmailed>false</ToBeEmailed>
    <ShipAddr>
      <Line1>Park Street</Line1>
      <City>Woodland Hills</City>
      <CountrySubDivisionCode>CA</CountrySubDivisionCode>
      <PostalCode>934657</PostalCode>
      <GeoCode>LAT=34.1785255,LNG=-118.597305</GeoCode>
      <Tag>CUSTOMER</Tag>
    </ShipAddr>
    <ShipMethodId idDomain="QBO" />
    <DepositToAccountId idDomain="QBO">4</DepositToAccountId>
    <DepositToAccountName>Undeposited Funds</DepositToAccountName>
    <DiscountTaxable>true</DiscountTaxable>
  </Header>
  <Line>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Desc>asdfdsafds</Desc>
    <Amount>500.00</Amount>
    <Taxable>true</Taxable>
    <ItemId>1</ItemId>
    <Qty>1</Qty>
  </Line>
</SalesReceipt>
```

I'll also try to reproduce the exact error msg. If I get something, I'll update it here.

**EDIT**

*GetById - (**Item id - 1**)*

```
<Item xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2" xmlns:qbp="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/qbopayroll/v1" xmlns:qbo="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/qbo">
    <Id idDomain="QBO">1</Id>
    <SyncToken>0</SyncToken>
    <MetaData>
        <CreateTime>2013-04-10T08:27:00-07:00</CreateTime>
        <LastUpdatedTime>2013-04-10T08:27:00-07:00</LastUpdatedTime>
    </MetaData>
    <Name>Services</Name>
    <Taxable>false</Taxable>
    <IncomeAccountRef>
        <AccountId idDomain="QBO">1</AccountId>
    </IncomeAccountRef>
</Item>
```

DocRef - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0400_quickbooks_online/item

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I thought the error might have something to do with the QBO account settings, and now I'm almost sure of it, since the request worked for you. I've been looking through the tabs endlessly, but nothing seems to indicate the cause of the error or what settings I should change.

Item with ID 5 does exist, but it has nothing to do with sales taxes. I was thinking that I may need an item to associate with the sales tax, but I'm not sure what it would be called or how it should work.

Comment: Can you please post the response of the getById API call for the ItemID 5.
I'm sharing the same in my original post. Please compare the same with that of yours. Please let me know how it goes.
Thanks

Comment: Please check if you have any IncomeAccount.

Comment: Updated. The responses seem pretty much functionally identical.

Answer (score 1):

In your SalesReceipt request line, you are passing the
< AccountId >52 . 
The Line item does not support this tag.
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0500_quickbooks_windows/0600_object_reference/salesreceipt

I think this might be the issue.